# Regex to get data from LaTeX string

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will return the following string data (in bold) from the following LaTeX scenarios.

1. Data between the last `&` and `\end`

   ```
   \begin{pmatrix}?&?\\?&?\\?&1+{\sqrt[3]{x}}\end{pmatrix}
   ```
2. Data between `matrix}` and `\end`

   ```
   \begin{bmatrix}1+{\sqrt[3]{x}}\end{bmatrix}
   ```
3. Data between `\\` and `\end`

   ```
   \begin{bmatrix}?\\1+2\end{bmatrix}
   ```

Given this string

```
\begin{pmatrix}?&?\\?&?\\?&1+{\sqrt[3]{x}}\end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1+{\sqrt[3]{x}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}?\\1+2\end{bmatrix}
```

I want to match these:

1. `1+{\sqrt[3]{x}}`
2. `1+{\sqrt[3]{x}}`
3. `1+2`

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you want to get the last (bottommost rightmost) cell contents of each matrix in the string? BTW why did you delete the regex you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Example 1 using `sed`

```
sed 's/\&\(.*\)\\end{pmatrix}/\1/'
```

You should be able to get the rest from there on.